# How to pass value for paramters in Crystal Report?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I found some ways by search google but it's not work for me. Here is my code:

```
thongkedonhang rpt = new thongkedonhang();
            ParameterFields pfields = new ParameterFields();
             ParameterField pfieldSTAFF = new ParameterField();
           ParameterDiscreteValue disValSTAFF = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
           disValSTAFF.Value = tungay;
           pfieldSTAFF.Name = "d1";
           pfieldSTAFF.CurrentValues.Add(disValSTAFF);

              pfields.Add(pfieldSTAFF);

         crpt_thongkedondh.ParameterFieldInfo = pfields;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
thongkedonhang rpt = new thongkedonhang();
thongkedonhang .SetParameterValue("ParameterName", disValSTAFF);
```

In place of `ParameterName` set the Valur of ypur `Parameter`

Comment: I'm really sorry. I'm not enough reputaion.

Comment: Could you tell me how I do this?

Comment: see the about menu in menu list for more detail